# Form submit not POST's the value in Django

Tags: python, django

When i just tried to save data using this simple form , it is not getting posted . Is there anything wrong in declaration of actions or url's ?

### Here the request.method is GET instead of POST even-though the form method is set as POST

Model file

```
   from django.db import models

   # Create your models here.
   class Contact(models.Model):

       name = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True, blank=True)
       company_id = models.CharField(max_length=30)

       def __unicode__(self):
           return self.name
```

Form.py uses the modelform

```
from contact.models import Contact
from django.forms import ModelForm

class AddcntForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
    model = Contact
```

Views

```
from contact.forms import AddcntForm
from django.contrib import messages
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response, redirect, get_object_or_404
from django.template.context import RequestContext

def add_cnt(request, form_class=AddcntForm):

    print request.method
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = form_class(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save(request)
            messages.success(request, "New Contact added.")
            return redirect('##success##')
    else:            
        form = form_class()
    return render_to_response(
    'vec/add_cnt.html',
    {'form': form},
    context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Url

```
from django.conf.urls import *
from django.conf import settings
urlpatterns = patterns('contact.views',   
   url(r'^addcnt/$', 'add_cnt', name='add_cnt'),    
)
```

template file is as follows

```
{% block content %}
<form method="post" action="/hr/addcnt/"   >{% csrf_token %}
{{ form.as_p }}
<input type="submit" value="Ok" />
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Why are you hardcofing the `action` value? You should use django's url creation.

Comment: @ThiefMaster yes i will, but i cannot able to figure out the issue here . This is just a test code .

Answer (score 2):

You're passing the `request.GET` querydict to your form when the method is `POST`. You should pass `request.POST` instead.

Also you're passing the request to `form.save()`. The only (optional) argument expected by `ModelForm.save()` is a boolean "commit" flag which, if true, prevent the form from effectively saving the instance (cf https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method). Remember that in Python each object have a boolean value... IOW you're saying the form to *not* save your instance ;)

Comment: sorry its just a typo. When i print the request.method it prints as GET instead of POST

Comment: Your view is called on both GET (to get the empty form) and POST (when submitting).

Comment: And there was indeed another problem with your code (answer edited...).

Answer (score 0):

I was confused too with the same issue.

When the form is called initially it is "GET" request so the statement -print request.method will print "GET".

After entering values in the form if you click on submit, you can see in the console the same statement -print request.method will print "POST" which is actually a post request.